# CSS: background image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using HTML and CSS in Vue.js application and my problem is the background image with full width below doesn't show without text being written and it adapt the added text with it's height (if I added one line of text it appeared as half image), is there a way to show the full width image with it's full height even if I added one line of text?

```html
<template>
   <b-container fluid>

<div class="image">
<b-row class="justify-content-center">
<b-col cols="4">
<h2>Overview</h2>
<p>text .....</p>

</b-col>
</b-row>
</div>

<div class="image-bottom">
<b-row class="justify-content-center">

</b-row>
</div>
  <router-view />
   </b-container>

</template>

<style scoped>

.image{
   background-image: url("../assets/images/contact.png");
 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.image-bottom{
   background-image: url("../assets/images/contact-bottom1.png") ;
   background-repeat: repeat;
 
   min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Did your try using ctrl + f5 to force reload the page?

Comment: You should show your CSS and some screenshots of the problem and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Making the `<template>` container the full height of the page should do the trick.

Add a CSS rule like shown:

```css
template {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Make sure you do simliar for the actual `<div>` you are adding this image to.

Without adding a height property to that element, it will shrink to the minimum height of the content. In this case it has none which explains why the image isn't showing up.